# How to install DnaSP on a Mac

Tags: genome, phylogenetics, software-installation

I need to install [DnaSp](http://www.ub.edu/dnasp/), a nice GUI originally written for Windows for the population genetics of nucleotide sequence data.

However, its not working on my mac. I'm using wine to install it using [these instructions for wine](http://www2.ub.es/dnasp/download.html). Wine usually successfully ports Windows programs.

it successfully installs but then I get this error

```
Mollies-MacBook-Air:dnasp51001 molliepassacantando$ WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 wine regsvr32.exe scrrun.dll mfc40.dll threed32.ocx
regsvr32: Successfully registered DLL 'scrrun.dll'
regsvr32: Successfully registered DLL 'mfc40.dll'
err:typelib:sltg_get_typelib_ref Unable to find reference
err:typelib:sltg_get_typelib_ref Unable to find reference
err:typelib:sltg_get_typelib_ref Unable to find reference
err:typelib:sltg_get_typelib_ref Unable to find reference
err:typelib:sltg_get_typelib_ref Unable to find reference
err:typelib:sltg_get_typelib_ref Unable to find reference
regsvr32: Successfully registered DLL 'threed32.ocx'
Mollies-MacBook-Air:dnasp51001 molliepassacantando$ winedevice.exe(30828,0x405ed000) malloc: *** error for object 0x401cea08: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and cannot run it.

Has anyone successfully installed DnaSp on a Mac or know of an alternate program I could use? I need to be able to calculate haplotype frequencies.

Comment: Hey, I see you found your way here. Great! But as I asked you on [ubuntu.se], why are you using wine? The DnaSP [authors state](http://www.ub.edu/dnasp/DnaSP_OS.html) that on a mac  "You can run DnaSP using SoftWindows, Virtual PC, Parallels Desktop or VMware Fusion software [sic]". Also, please [edit] your question and explain the kind of analysis you need to do. The vast majority of bioinformatics tools don't work on Windows and work fine on a UNIX-based system like Mac. There are almost certainly other choices but we need to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Bioiformatics stack exchange. We can not suggest you an alternative if we do not understand your problem. Could you [edit] your question to elaborate bit more what you want to use the software for?

Comment: @kamil i need it to calculate haplotype frequencies, im using wine because i wasnt sure what other platform to use, and i dont want to pay for software, as i found you needed to do with the suggested programs

Comment: @MolliePassacantando that sounds reasonable, I bet there will be a lot of free softwares doing that. However, please [edit] your question so people do not have to search this information in comments. Also do not hesitate to add more information about software you already tried...

Comment: @terdon i have edited the question, and am not sure why i cannot run the program with a mac. the file i download from the website is a .msi, which i open using wine, because mac does not read that format

Comment: This looks like a WINE error unrelated to DnaSp. How did you install it?

Comment: youre right! it was a WINE error, I managed to get the error to stop showing up, but im not sure how. but it works!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments @MollePasscantando successfully ported DNAsp onto a Mac (Air) via Wine, but was not sure how. This is good news because Wine is very commonly used for porting Windows exes. The website states,

> Oracle VirtualBox (free open-source). Parallels, CrossOver, VMware
> Fusion (paid-versions; trial period)

From the website it was update in February 26, 2019 and its current Beta Version is 6.12.03.

There was a major [published](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29029172/) update to the package in Mol Biol Evol in 2017 (version 6) for large data sets (NGS).

Thus the question is still relevant because they still have not written an OSX specific version and this will limit its performance for the data sets it is now targeted for.